# テキストの同じ行に2つの文字列がある行だけを抽出

Tags: python, python3

```
onetwothreefourfive
onetwofour
onethreefourfive
onetwofive
```

というテキストから文字列one、threeだけのある行を抽出して

```
onetwothreefourfive
onethreefourfive
```

というテキストを作成したいのですがどうすればよいでしょうか。

Comment: 「事前に与えられた文字列を全て含む行を抽出」、ということでよろしいですか？

Answer (score 1):

oneの後にthreeが出てくる語順ならば下記の正規表現で抽出可能です。

```
import re
s = """onetwothreefourfive
onetwofour
onethreefourfive
onetwofive""" 
s2 = '\n'.join(re.findall(r'^.*one.*three.*$', s, re.MULTILINE))
print(s2)
```

Answer (score 1):

文字列を行単位で扱いたい時は、`splitlines()`を使って、行単位の文字列のリストにしてしまうのが便利です。

```
s = """onetwothreefourfive
onetwofour
onethreefourfive
onetwofive"""
```

として、for文によるループ処理ならば、以下のようなコードでかけます。

```
result = ''
for line in s.splitlines(True):
    if 'one' in line and 'three' in line:
        result += line
```

また、内包式を使うと次のように書けます。

```
result = ''.join(x for x in s.splitlines(True) if 'one' in x and 'three' in x)
```

なお、`splitlines(True)`とすると改行文字がついたままでリストになるので、改行文字の機種依存を考慮しなくても処理が可能です。